# How to prove that the product of two divergent limits is divergent.

Tags: limits

I'm trying to prove that, if $a_n\rightarrow\infty$ and if $b_n\rightarrow\infty$, then $a_nb_n\rightarrow \infty$.
Here's my proof:
[image]

But what happens when $0<K<1,$ in which case $K>K^2$?

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't matter. The definition means that if you happen to be given $K<1$ then it will be covered by say, the case $K=1$. Just give it a think; an $N$ that works for some $K$ also works for every $K' < K$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow.

Comment: Given some $K$, you can find an $N$ such that $a_n>K$ whenever $n>N$. Now if you wanted $a_n>L$ where $L<K$, then of course $n>N$ will still work; we'll have $a_n>K>L$. The same will apply to the product, just with some slightly fiddly details to write.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Should I explain the last bit in the proof or can I just say that it's trivially true for $K<1$?

Comment: Well, I guess it's a matter of why you're writing this proof. If it is some form of coursework then I'd write out the details fully (as I always have with any coursework!), but otherwise some form of explanation as why it won't matter would be enough, if the reader could see the detail for themselves from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you prove the statement for large K it is automatically proven for any smaller K:  We know eventually the product is bigger than 10000000 so of course it is eventually bigger than 1/2.

If you're writing out a neat proof, for K between 0 and 1, just take N to be whatever it would be for K=1.